# Stuck at "How to Ask" page when trying to ask a question on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions

I've gone through the FAQ on Stack Overflow but see what's written here

> We’d love to help you. But not every question on Stack Overflow gets
>   answered. To improve your chances, here are some tips:

Every time I try to find the text area where I can write my question's title and ask my independent question but instead I get a search bar which searches my category of question. If it is not able to search, then there is a display like this :

> No questions found with related titles. Try our more advanced
>   search!

I don't want to search my question. I want to ASK my own. I think it sounds like 'spoon feed' but I really need it.

Comment: You did click on the big "Ask Question" button?

Comment: yes, after that BIG 'Ask Question' button also I was NOT getting what I needed..

Comment: Then what were you getting. Take a snapshot and show us

Comment: Are you getting something that looks like the screenshot Bart included in his answer? If not, show us what you are getting!

Comment: I wonder how you were able to ask a question here. The process is the same. I clearly do not understand what your problem is.

Comment: "Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images."

Comment: I can't upload snapshot

Comment: @ankitaP - give the link of the screenshot here.

Comment: @him056 - Try this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?

Comment: That's the "How to Ask" page. Click on the checkbox in the bottom left corner and click "Proceed".

Answer (score 6):

If you're stuck on the "How to Ask" page, read the page, and in the bottom left corner, click on the checkbox and then click on "proceed".

> [image]

Other than that it's pretty simple really and exactly the same process as on Meta Stack Overflow. First, click on the big "Ask Question" button.

> [image]

Then fill out your title, the actual question and any relevant tags.

> [image]

Click on "Post your question" and you should be good to go.

Comment: This is all allowed to me in "meta stackoverflow" not "stack overflow" whatever you showed was not there. And I can't upload image. "Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because: We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images."

Comment: Put it on imgur or whatever and link to it.

Comment: otherwise I would have upload the snapshot. Thank you.